# Line break in text above arrow

Tags: arrows

I have the following arrow and text:

```
\arrow{->[conjugation/hydroxylation/oxidation]}[0,2]
```

How do I insert a line break between `conjugation/hydroxylation/` and `oxidation`? I've tried `\break`, `\\` and `\newline` all followed by a blank, but I'm not getting any changes. Basically, I want `conjugation\hydroxylation` and `oxidation` to be stacked one over the other above the arrow.

I've also tried `\substack{}` from `amsmath`, but the word `oxidation` disappears.

Here's an example image (doesn't have to look identical):

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use \parbox

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
    \schemestart
    \chemfig{**6(--(-COOR)-(-COOR)---)}
    \arrow{->[\parbox{2cm}{conjugation \\ hydroxylation \\ oxidation}][]}[0,2]
    \chemfig{**6(--(-COOR)-(-COOH)---)}
    \arrow{->}
    \chemfig{**6(--(-[:-30](=[:-90]O)-[:30]O-[:-30]R)-(-[:30](=[:90]O)-[:-30]O-[:30](*6(-(-OH)-(-OH)-(-OH)-(-COOH)-O-)))---)}
    \schemestop
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can use  `\centering` too

```
\arrow{->[\parbox{2cm}{\centering conjugation \\hydroxylation \\ oxidation}][]}[0,2]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Since `chemfig` uses TikZ we should be able to do this with just setting `align = center` for that node.

Unfortunately, `chemfig` neither uses PGFKeys nor does it offer a good interface to change all or only one of the arrow's nodes.

It does however has an interface to declare new arrow types.
Here, I declare the arrow type `->*` with three (user) arguments where the first two are the two nodes along the arrow and the third can be options for the two nodes.

I've also added the style `chemfig/every ->* node` so that you can declare a common style for all those labels. Sneaking that in via `\CF_arrowdisplaylabel` works because its second and sixth argument isn't protected when it is forwarded to the `pos` key.

I'm using the `\chemfig`s from the other answer to show this off since I don't know `\chemfig` otherwise.

Of course, this needs to be extended to other arrow types (or the original ones can be overwritten) to have this functionality available for all types.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\catcode`\_=11
\definearrow4{->*}{%
  \CF_arrowshiftnodes{#4}%
  \draw[style/.expand once=\CF_arrowcurrentstyle]
    (\CF_arrowstartnode)--(\CF_arrowendnode);%
  \CF_arrowdisplaylabel{#1}{0.5,chemfig/every ->* node,#3}+%
     \CF_arrowstartnode{#2}{0.5,chemfig/every ->* node,#3}-\CF_arrowendnode}
\catcode`\_=8
\tikzset{chemfig/every ->* node/.append style={align=center, font=\scriptsize}}
\begin{document}

\schemestart
  \chemfig{**6(--(-COOR)-(-COOR)---)}
  \arrow{->*[conjugation/hydroxylation \\ oxidation]}[0,2]
  \chemfig{**6(--(-COOR)-(-COOH)---)}
\schemestop

\schemestart
  \chemfig{**6(--(-COOR)-(-COOR)---)}
  \arrow{->*[conjugation/\\ hydroxylation \\ oxidation][Both nodes!][
    blue, align=left, draw, rounded corners, inner sep=.15em,
    font=\normalsize\bfseries]}[0,2]
  \chemfig{**6(--(-COOR)-(-COOH)---)}
\schemestop
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Using a `tabular` frees you from guessing the size.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}

\schemestart
  \chemfig{**6(--(-COOR)-(-COOR)---)}
  \arrow{->[\scriptsize\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}} conjugation/hydroxylation \\ oxidation \end{tabular}][]}[0,2]
  \chemfig{**6(--(-COOR)-(-COOH)---)}
\schemestop

\end{document}
```

[image]

Change `\scriptsize` to the size command you prefer.