# Multiline text above arrow or relation symbol

Tags: equations, mathtools, xrightarrow, arrowwithtext

One way of writing text above an arrow symbol is to use \xrightarrow from mathtools:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
    \begin{equation*}
        \dfrac{x+1}{x} \xrightarrow{\text{euclidean division}} 1+\dfrac{1}{x}
    \end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image: Example]

But if the words are quite long, it might be preferable to have one word above the other and have that stack be above the arrow.

In other words, using the example above, the words *euclidean*, *division* and the arrow would be stacked on top of the other, in that order, with the arrow line still being aligned (somewhat) with the division line on the left.

Trying the following does not work:

```
\xrightarrow{\text{euclidean\\division}}
```

Is there a simple way to do this? Abbreviating the words or using other words is not an option.

Comment: This might help: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/666115/

Comment: @barbara beeton Doing this: \xrightarrow{\parbox{2cm}{\centering\scriptsize euclidean \\ division}}) does the job for now. However, without the \scriptsize, the text is too big. The arrow is also not resized properly to the new \scriptsize and looks a bit too long. Thank you for the suggestion. I will leave the question open in case someone else has another idea.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `\overset` for this purpose. The default has the overset in `\scriptscriptstyle`, so you need to resize.

[image]

It can be placed into a macro as in the following code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\newcommand{\twoline}[2]{\overset{\textup{\scriptsize #1}}{\textup{#2}}}


\begin{document}
    \begin{equation*}
        \dfrac{x+1}{x} \xrightarrow{\twoline{Euclidean}{division}} 1+\dfrac{1}{x}
    \end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @VincentKrebs it isn't `mathtools` that is required here, only `amsmath` (which is auto loaded by `mathtools`)

Comment: @daleif Yes, I am aware.

Comment: I have edited the code so that `mathtools` is loaded before calling `\overset`. I know it compiles but the reader must be informed that the command is not part of the kernel, as it requires `amsmath` (which in turn is included in `\mathtools`).

Comment: I left `mathtools` in the code since OP had it and I assumed it was used somewhere else in their document.

Answer (score 6):

Another solution using  `extarrows` package. This is the principal code:

```
\frac{x+1}{x} \xlongrightarrow{\begin{matrix} \textup{Euclidean} &\\[-.3em] \textup{division}\end{matrix}}1+\dfrac{1}{x}
```

---

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools,extarrows}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  \frac{x+1}{x} \xlongrightarrow{\begin{matrix} \textup{Euclidean} &\\[-.3em] \textup{division}\end{matrix}}1+\dfrac{1}{x}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I'd use a `tabular` inside `\text`, but there's a little complication: `\text` doesn't update `\baselineskip`, but this can be fixed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\textsubstack}{O{}m}
 {% #1 = optional font declaration, #2 = text
  \textnormal{%
    \fontsize{\f@size}{\fpeval{\f@size*\f@baselineskip/10}}
    \selectfont
    #1
    \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}#2\end{tabular}%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[
\frac{x+1}{x}\xrightarrow{\textsubstack{Euclidean \\ division }}1+\frac{1}{x}
\]

\[
\frac{x+1}{x}\xrightarrow{\textsubstack[\itshape]{Euclidean \\ division }}1+\frac{1}{x}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]